# Flash / ActionScript3 compiled sources size / difference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to nail down the following thing. I have my domain-specific flash framework with a set of basic classes. I created empty FLA and assigned main class - D. When I inspect size report after compilation I see a picture like this:

```
2121    Scene 1:Frame 1:A
 280    Scene 1:Frame 1:B
 416    Scene 1:Frame 1:C
1002    Scene 1:Frame 1:D
 422    Scene 1:Frame 1:E
```

Then I place in several layers with animation on timeline - everything comes from a designer and doesn't have a code related to framework inside. Size report is changed to:

```
2854    Scene 1:Frame 1:A
 376    Scene 1:Frame 1:B
 560    Scene 1:Frame 1:C
1348    Scene 1:Frame 1:D
 581    Scene 1:Frame 1:E
```

Taking into account that this is just a snippet of report I have a size growth up to 5-6 KB for every 40KB of compiled code (not debug, no swc, no size report) that makes a huge difference when you have a size restrictions.

All compilator preferences are kept the same before attempts. Player version and all checkboxes are kept the same too.

So the question is who come that I have such difference in size when compile same code with and without animation pasted. Is there anything that Flash includes into compiled classes automatically based on timeline?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking why your SWF/FLA file gets bigger when you add the animations to it.

Is that what you're asking??

Comment: @Prpl_Ppl_Etr: not exactly, because there's a good reason for SWF to get bigger with animations in. I'm comparing AS *compiled* code size only for particular classes I own.

Comment: Do you compile everything into just one SWF or several?  And: How do you get the size report with "no size report"?

Comment: Oh, I just thought of something: Are there any library symbols within the animation sequences? All symbols from the library, even if they only extend MovieClip or Sprite and no custom classes, are compiled into frame 1, if the option is checked.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: everything is compiled into a single SWF. "No size report" is confusing - I meant without class-by-class report, only short one that shows overall AS size. There are library classes compiled into Frame 1 in both cases- with and without layering structure + animations. Without layer+animation: "188 Scene 1:Frame 1:backgroundLoaderMC". With them in: "253 Scene 1:Frame 1:backgroundLoaderMC"

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't have any timeline script in the frames, the objects on the stage still need to be initialized, added and animated somehow. This is done by instructions in the swf file (called tags). A swf file is basically just a header and series of tags. The description of the animation created with a flash authoring tool gets converted to tags too. I guess those instructions add up to the frame's code size the timeline objects are are defined in.

Comment: I understand that it takes some code to do initialization of all the objects on stage and I have no problem with this. Though I don't understand why Flash shows different sizes from my own classes when objects are added to stage? There's nothing happened to these classes AFAIK.

Comment: @eduard.dudar So the classes are completely unrelated to the objects? In that case I don't have an answer. Maybe decompiling the file could shed some light on this.